# How can I make the icon that goes before the website "title"?

Tags: html

I am making a small website and I want to know how to make that little icon that goes next to the website name (I have no clue what it is called.), and how to put it there.

Comment: http://www.favicon.cc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a favicon what you need.

Between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags

Add this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.faviconer.com/uploads/24/263/favicon.png" />
```

`href=""` => icon of the image (in example is this a link to an icon)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is known as [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```